# In topological data analysis, do bar codes that begin and end at the same index mean anything?

Tags: data-mining, topology

The typical workflow in topological data analysis is from point cloud data to *filtration* to a list of bar codes corresponding to each dimension.

A filtration is a sequence of simplicial complexes, each one a subset of the next; where a simplicial complex is a gluing of many simplices such that the intersection of any two simplices (if it exists) is a simplex. Each simplicial complex can be obtained from the point cloud data by, for example, taking a sequence of distances and connecting points which fall within that distance to form a graph, then identifying complete subgraphs as simplices to make a simplicial complex. This is called the Vietoris-Rips complex. Another common way to construct a filtration is the Cech complex, which makes a simplex out of a set of points iff balls of a certain radius intersect.

The filtration is the input to the algorithm which computes *persistent homology*. Simplicial homology is the simplest of homology theories and it allows one to identify connected components, tunnels, hollow volumes, and higher dimensional cavities in a simplicial complex. Persistent homology does the same for filtrations, except it also measures how long each cluster/hole lasts in the sequence of complexes. The computation is a bit tricky, to learn about it I would refer you to [the paper that showed that the computation is actually practical](https://geometry.stanford.edu/papers/zc-cph-05/zc-cph-05.pdf). The output of persistent homology is a *bar code diagram* for each dimension. A bar code has a beginning, which is the index in the filtration where the cluster/hole begins, and it might have an end where the cluster/hole dies.

So it seems natural to disregard bar codes that have the same beginning and end; they don't persist at all. Even if a feature is present only in the ith complex in the filtration, it will have the bar code (i, i+1) because it dies in the (i+1)th complex.

However, I want to be completely sure because I'm maintaining a TDA package. I just finished a patch and was considering adding an extra feature where these apparently meaningless bar codes are automatically filtered out.

Comment: From [here](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~ghrist/preprints/barcodes.pdf) it seems that the barcodes are the *outcome* of the analysis. Perhaps you can expand your question by a few more paragraphs, explaining more of the situation?

Comment: YuvalFilmus do my editions suffice?

Comment: Thanks, that's much better. Hopefully someone knowledgeable would reply.